# File not found when redirecting through hyperlink in php

Tags: php

I want to know how to access a file which is in inner folder in php. I am using following path I want to traverse from home.php to login.php. Thanks...

```
<a href="account/login.php">Log in</a>
```

and my directory structure is as follows:

```
MainSite >
   accountFolder >> register.php , login.php
css
js
images
home.php
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path `<a href="/account/login.php">Log In</a>`

Comment: Links without preceding `/` are relative to the current URI, those with it are added to the end of the domain.

Comment: I have used http://localhost/account/login.php but result is The requested URL /account/login.php was not found on this server.

Comment: If you are on linux, make sure `file names` are case sensitive.

Comment: no i am using windows

Comment: MainSite is my project name, but when i use <a href="../account/login.php">Log in</a> it calls localhost/account/login.php rather than localhost/MainSite/account/login.php